# reset password link is not working properly in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi guys i am trying to send  email to users with link for reset password.when they clicked on forgot password it will ask them to submit their email.if they gave their correct email it will send mail to them with  token link.i have generated 16 digit random number.so when i try to pass email and token number in link but some reason its not passing those two values.

here is my code:

```
public function ForgotPassword()
{
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $findemail = $this->Login_model->forgotPassword($email);
    $token = random_string('alnum', 16);
    if ($findemail) {

        $config = [
            'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => 'do-not-reply@example.com', // change it to yours
            'smtp_pass' => 'password', // change it to yours
            'mailtype' => 'html',
            'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
            'wordwrap' => true
        ];


        $message = 'Please click on below link to reset your password';

        $message .= "<a href='http://localhost/SVN/Project_X/Login/resetpassword/email='.$email.'/token='.$token.'>test</a>";
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->from('do-not-reply@example.com'); // change it to yours

        $this->email->to($email); // change it to yours
        $this->email->subject('Message from Project_X for reset your password');
        $this->email->message($message);
        if ($this->email->send()) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata(
                'message',
                'We have sent you email for reset your password!Please check your email'
            );
            $this->load->view('login_view');
        } else {
            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
        }

    } else {
        //echo "<script>alert(' $email not found, please enter correct email id')</script>";
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Mail  not found, please enter correct email id');
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
}
```

Can any one explain me what mistake i have done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You set it `exit` before creating link?

Comment: if i remove also its not coming let me remove that

Comment: Change `/email='.$email.'/token='.$token.'>` to `/email=$email&token=$token`. Your `'` are actually closing the `href`-tag so you're currently adding the variables _after_ the href attribute.

Comment: was an email even being sent with the exit line? that seems weird...

Comment: no it wont sent if i set it as exit

Comment: please do not post real credentials here... you have to change them now

Comment: yeah sorry forgot..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below code

**Solution1**

```
$token=random_string('alnum', 16);      
$email = 'test@test.com';
$message .="<a href='http://localhost/SVN/Project_X/Login/resetpassword/$email/$token'>test</a>";
```

Access your email and token field via uri segment ci functionality.

```
$this->uri->segment()
```

**Solution2**

You can setup reset password page as below

[image]

1) Generate reset password page URL with the token like below example and sent below link in user email.

```
$token=random_string('alnum', 16);
$confirmationLink = base_url().'Login/resetpassword/'.$verificationCode;
```

2) Create 1 field in user table (for store token value) of forgot password user.

3) Create function as below in your login controller

```
public function resetpassword($token=NULL){ echo $token; }
```

4) With the use of the token, you can identify if the token exists in database then show user to reset password page otherwise show 404 page

5) While user submits the new password simply just need to update the password in a token row.

Comment: hi i ahve one more doubt from php can i ask

Comment: Yes suresh please

Comment: can you please create chat so there i can show my code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174024/discussion-between-evince-development-and-suresh).

Comment: hi how can i get token value in update_password function

Comment: hi i  have one doubt may i ask

Comment: If new topic then please post a new question and give me the link here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282113/logout-the-user-from-website-if-they-meet-the-expiry-time-from-database-in-codei

Comment: Hi i have one doubt

Answer (score 3):

Just remove single quote `''` from your link and use double quote `""`.

Try this:

```
$message .="<a href='http://localhost/SVN/Project_X/Login/resetpassword/email=".$email."/token=".$token.">test</a>";
```

Comment: Talk about low-hanging fruit. You beat me to it.