# Logout the user from website if they meet the expiry time from database in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to logout the user from website if they meet the expiry time which i have stored in database.
I have create a table called **user_sessions**  where i have stored current **userid**,**logintime(varchar)**,**expirytime(varchar)** and i have added one minute extra to the login time in expiry time field  so when user logged in these are all values will store in db.

So after user logged in they are redirecting to dashboard so if user doesn't do anything on site up to one minute and if they try to access next page they should logout from site.

If user keep on moving to next pages i need to add one more minute extra time in login time field everytime when they moved to next pages.

I have stored in db like this

Here is my model:

```
  public function sessionStore($data)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('username', $data['username']);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $recordId = $result[0]['id'];
        $status = $result[0]['status'];
        $sessionID = random_string('alnum',16);
        $currentpass = $result[0]['password'];
        if ($status != 1) {
            return 4;
        }
        $checktrue = password_verify($data['password'], $currentpass);
       // $checktrue = true;
        if ($checktrue) {
            $data_log = array(
                'userid' => $recordId,
                'sessionid' => $sessionID,
                'logintime' => time(),
                'expirytime' => time()+(60*1)
             );
            $this->db->insert('user_sessions', $data_log);
            return 1;
        } 
    } 
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
 public function login_user() {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    } else {
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => $this->input->post('password')
        );
        $result = $this->Login_model->login($data);
        $res = $this->Login_model->sessionStore($data);

        if ($result == 1) {
            $userData = $this->Login_model->getUserData($data);
            $sessionArray = array(
                'is_logged' => TRUE,
                'user_name' => $data['username'],
                'first_name' => $userData['firstname'],
                'last_name' => $userData['lastname'],
                'userlevel' => $userData['userlevel'],
                'organisation_id' => $userData['organisation_id'],
                'user_id' => $userData['id'],
                'lastip' => $userData['lastip']

            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($sessionArray);
            redirect('dashboard');
        } else if ($result == 2) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Password seems to be wrong!');
            $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        } else if ($result == 4) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Username is not active!');
            $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        }else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Username not found!');
            $this->load->view('login_view', $data);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me how to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, you need to create `common_model.php` and define into `autoload.php`. This way you just need to write code in single file only. Hope this will help you!

Comment: not clear exactly. can you please explain it briefly.if you are free can you please tell me step by step so i will write code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

Create **Common_model.php** file `\application\models\Common_model.php`

Add common_model in **autoload.php** `\application\config\autoload.php`

```
$autoload['model'] = array('common_model');
```

Write the below code inside **Common_model.php**.

```
<?php
class Common_model extends CI_Model {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->checkUserActivity();
    }
    public function checkUserActivity(){
        $this->db->where('expirytime >=',time());        
        $this->db->where('userid',$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
        $result = $this->db->get('user_sessions')->first_row(); 
        /* Check If user active within 1 minute then add 1 minute more*/
        if($result){ // Update
            $data_log = array(                
                'expirytime' => time()+(60*1)
             );
            $this->db->where('userid',$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
            $this->db->update('user_sessions', $data_log);
        } else {//Logout
            $this->activityLogout();
        }
        //echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;
    }

    public function activityLogout()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('user_id'); // single unset
        $this->session->sess_destroy(); // Unset all your
        redirect('home', 'refresh');
    }
}
?>
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: give me 5 minutes let me check that

Comment: redirect('home', 'refresh'); //this will redieect to login page or dahsboard page

Comment: Above code is redirect to the homepage but you may change it to default controller. i.e. login. `redirect('controller_name', 'refresh');`

Comment: when i did like this  redirect('Login'); it is showing this error  This page isn’t working

Comment: Login is my controller name..it is redirecting to correct URL only but view page is not visible

Comment: If you have developed logout code then simply put the code inside **activityLogout** function and redirect

Comment: okay..here is my logout code $this->Login_model->saveLogout();
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('/.');  can i put this

Comment: one more thing this functionality has to work once they logged in to site it should not check for login page.in our case its not login me into the site because its applying for login also

Comment: yes try to put `$this->session->sess_destroy(); redirect('/.'); ` code. Yes functionality worked once they logged in. please replace code in __construct `if($this->session->userdata('user_id')){
            $this->checkUserActivity();
        }`

Comment: hi i have one small doubt

Comment: may i ask if you are free

Comment: Yes, Can you please describe your issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416404/depending-on-from-and-to-dates-excel-report-need-to-download-in-php can you please check that question

Comment: i have done but still its coming some issues i don't think so whether that is correct way or not..i am getting error if i didn't meat the conditions  from post

Comment: As I have checked you did the correct way but again need to check the exact error. Can you please put the `IF` condition, If you get the records from `SELECT` query then only execute the excel `$objWriter->save('php://output');` code.

Comment: i have one doubt may i ask